# AngularJS directives with HTML5 drag and drop -- issue with scope object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm fairly new to angular and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around where the items are being pushed to. I am not sure if I am correctly setting up the functions to be used with drag/drop and if its getting bound to an older scope object and the ng-repeat isn't being updated properly. I'm thinking there is some slight issue with the way I have this setup. Any pointers or help would be much appreciated.

What should happen is when you drag a color from the Draggable container into the Droppable container it should update the text which is linked to the scope object items. I am successfully pushing an item onto the scope object but ng-repeat isn't picking it up. I am not sure if I need a watch or what to do to get it to pay attention to the newly added items.

JS Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/RV23R/

HTML CODE:

```
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="MainController">
<div class="container">
    <header><h1>Draggables</h1></header>
    <section>
        <div draggable="true" ng-repeat="drag_type in drag_types">{{drag_type.name}}</div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <header><h1>Drop Schtuff Here</h1></header>
    <section droppable="true">
        <div><span>You dragged in: </span><span ng-repeat="items in items">{{item.name}},</span></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

ANGULAR CODE:

```
var module = angular.module('my-app', []);

module.directive('draggable', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element[0].addEventListener('dragstart', scope.handleDragStart, false);
      element[0].addEventListener('dragend', scope.handleDragEnd, false);
    }
  }
});

module.directive('droppable', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element[0].addEventListener('drop', scope.handleDrop, false);
      element[0].addEventListener('dragover', scope.handleDragOver, false);
    }
  }
});

function MainController($scope)
{
    $scope.drag_types = [
        {name: "Blue"},
        {name: "Red"},
        {name: "Green"},
    ];
    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.handleDragStart = function(e){
        this.style.opacity = '0.4';
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', this.innerHTML);
    };

    $scope.handleDragEnd = function(e){
        this.style.opacity = '1.0';
    };

    $scope.handleDrop = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var dataText = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
        $scope.items.push(dataText);
        console.log($scope.items);
    };

    $scope.handleDragOver = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';  // See the section on the DataTransfer object.
        return false;
  };

}
```

CSS (if anyone cares)

```
.container {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: verdana;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

.container header {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( top, #f1f1f1, #CCC );
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( top, #f1f1f1, #CCC );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( top, #f1f1f1, #CCC );
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient( top, #f1f1f1, #CCC );
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #888;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px white;
  color: #888;
  text-align: center;
}

.container section {
  padding: 10px 30px; 
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 175%;
  color: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of typos in the fiddle, but the basic problem is that your drag events are outside an angular digest cycle.  You should wrap your changes in `$scope.$apply` (code sample coming).  This forked and bugfixed [(FIDDLE)](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/NWnF8/) shows that when you click the button, angular shows the changes and refreshes the display with new values.

Fix: [(FIDDLE)](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/CPRda/1/)

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.items.push(dataText);
});
```

A bug you had is in this code:

```
<span ng-repeat="items in items">{{item.name}},</span>
```

This should probably be `ng-repeat="item in items"`, also items only contains the dropped text so it is an array of strings and not the original item objects.

Comment: Yeah I had a few people in the JS Fiddle so it may have been changed. Thanks for the help!